# Stop automatic URL decoding in PHP/Drupal

Tags: php, jquery, drupal

I am sending a custom XML data from jQuery to Drupal/PHP as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',       
            url: this.href,

            success: function(data){ 

                alert('Form is successfully saved');


            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus,  errorThrown){
                alert("Error");

            },

            data: 'myxml='+ mydata 
        });
```

My XML tags contains URLs, so I encode them, and before making an AJAX call, data looks somewhat like this:

```
mydata="<txtLinkLocation>http%3A%2F%2Fportal.cubewerx.com%2Fcubewerx%2Fcubeserv%2Fcubeserv.cgi%3FCONFIG%3Dhaiti%26SERVICE%3DWFS%26DATASTORE%3DOSM%26request%3DGetCapabilities</txtLinkLocation>";
```

And, in PHP I get the received data, and I store it as follows:

```
$receivedXML = $_POST['myxml'];
```

Now, contains of $receivedXML looks like this:

```
<txtLinkLocation>http://portal.cubewerx.com/cubewerx/cubeserv/cubeserv.cgi?CONFIG=haiti&SERVICE=WFS&DATASTORE=OSM&request=GetCapabilities</txtLinkLocation>
```

My question is why URL inside this string is being been automatically decoded? Why is this happening? I do not want any automatic operation to be performed on data that is being sent through AJAX call. How to stop this behavior? I feel like I am missing some fundamental concepts here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_POST data is sent to the server in the same way as $_GET. It has to be sent urlencoded else it may break. This means that by default, PHP will decode urlencodes because it expects the data to be urlencoded.

Answer (score 1):

PHP decodes $_GET and $_REQUEST data it by default, see [the note in urldecoding on auto-encoding server variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).  Turns out that $_POST does too.

Solution:  `urlencode()` your data again if you want it to be encoded.